# All PyPI packages which use a given package

Tags: python, pypi

For a package which it available on PyPI, is there a way to get a list of all PyPI packages which have that package as a dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible, not because PyPI lacks such an API, but because it's not technically possible due to how Python packages are structured and created.

See: https://di.codes/articles/2018/03/05/why-pypi-doesnt-know-dependencies for an in-depth explanation.